# Question on scheduling pipeline through Azure data factory using private endpoint

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory, endpoint

I have questions on build "Managed private endpoints" for the pipeline which copies data from azure SQL DB to azure Blob storage which will be scheduled for running once a month automatically.

My question 1 is: when I create new integration runtime, I have to set interactive authoring and the connection will auto terminated after 60 mins. Does that mean every time I have to manually enable interactive authoring? My status of connection always shows in red rectangle:

[image: Interactive authoring disabled message from ADF UI]

Only after manual enable it, the connect test could succeed.
And my managed private endpoint looks fine.

The question 2 is: even I choose Account selection method using "From Azure subscription", it would be back to "Enter manually", and seems this kind change could not be published, so the updating never to be saved.  Any difference effect to pipeline between  "From Azure subscription" and "Enter Manually"?

And now, even my pipeline can be run successfully once I manually enable interactive authoring, it would fail in future scheduled jobs as following, and status as "In progress":

[image: Overview of monitoring with triggered pipeline runs in progress]

Hope I explained my situation clear to you guys, and welcome any suggestions.

Comment: "Interactive Authoring" has no effect on scheduled jobs. So you don't need to worry about your scheduled job not running.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you enable interactive writing or begin a pipeline run, a
   session is initiated. The session should persist for the duration of
   the TTL before being terminated. When you start a session, a virtual
   machine is built to execute the session. The first delay is most
   likely caused by the virtual machine creating and powering up.

   This is the Original Post which could be referred - [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/130531/issue-with-azure-ir-in-adf-with-managed-virtual-ne.html).
2. By default ADF will show in enter manual mode only all settings.

   Even if you fill details from subscription, still when you publish
   and reopen linked serivce it always shows in Enter manual mode only'